# AMW Service inventory not appearing in seller central despite submitting OK

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have 3 marketplaces (DE, UK, IT), primary is DE and the other marketplaces is loaded from DE (we control inventory by AMW Service API) but now we wont to use separated all marketplaces.
For tests we disconnect UK marketplace, remove products and now I try to submit feed to UK marketplace. Here is _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ submit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>PartialUpdate</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>0000036869</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>EAN</Type>
                <Value>5907695571806</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
            </Condition>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Skateboard, Fishboard, Recreational riding Nils</Title>
                <Brand>Nils</Brand>
                <Description>SKATEBOARD by NILS

    Skateboard with a robust plastic material, called polypropylene (PP) - skateboards are stronger than with conventional skateboards made of plywood.

     Thanks to the truss on the upper side skateboard possessed better grip, more stability, safe driving, the effect of non slip.

    The advantage is surely the small size of skateboards, so fits easily into even a small backpack, and interesting colors.


</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Dimensions: 58 x 15.5 cm, Material: polypropylene (PP), Truck: 3.25, Bearings: ABEC-5,</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Wheels: PU 60 x 45 mm,Hardness 78A,Maximum user weight: 100kg,Color: green,Color wheels: yellow,</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>A robust, Durable, Truss on the top side with a grip enhancing, Stable,</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Small size allows placement of skateboards in a backpack,</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Bent back part of the board.</BulletPoint>
                <Manufacturer>Nils</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>SportingGoods</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Sports>
                    <ProductType>SportingGoods</ProductType>
                </Sports>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <OperationType>PartialUpdate</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>0000027472</SKU>
            <StandardProductID>
                <Type>EAN</Type>
                <Value>5907695581935</Value>
            </StandardProductID>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
            </Condition>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Replaceable plates on sticks Nordic Walking 2 pcs. Nils</Title>
                <Brand>Nils</Brand>
                <Description>PLATES FOR NORDIC WALKING POLES

    2pcs.

    Set of two interchangeable plates for Nordic Walking sticks, to prevent collapse of the sticks in the ground and mud.


</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Material: plastic,</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Diameter: approx. 5 cm,</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Set: 2 pieces,</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Color: black.</BulletPoint>
                <Manufacturer>Nils</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>SportingGoods</ItemType>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Sports>
                    <ProductType>SportingGoods</ProductType>
                </Sports>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

And after submit, few minutes later I check submission (using GetFeedSubmissionResult), response above:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_FIRMAHANDL_1586538</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>420618017358</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary>
                <MessagesProcessed>2</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>2</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>0</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

But in my seller central inventory not appearing...
I read lot of topics but no with luck.

I even try to do next thing - send UK MarketplaceIdList change price feed  (_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <Price>
            <SKU>0000036869</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="GBP">27.73</StandardPrice>
        </Price>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

response:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_FIRMAHANDL_1586538</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>420724017358</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary>
                <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>1</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>0</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

And the last one, _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_ feed:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>AJICEPNWN291Z</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Inventory>
            <SKU>0000036869</SKU>
            <Quantity>92</Quantity>
        </Inventory>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

and response:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_FIRMAHANDL_1586538</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>420709017358</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary>
                <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>1</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>0</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

After this steps still there is no products in UK inventory ...
All feeds points to UK marketplace (i think - MarketplaceIdList have [ "Id" => "UK_MARKETPLACE_ID"])
I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. We have one product left which still exists in UK marketplace because not all product details fields was filled correctly (first fill all fields, then you can delete product).